# Understanding states in Firebase Dynamic links for Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I am sorry i have much trouble understanding Firebase Dynamic links.

My use case is : a user wants to reset his password from the mobile app (or send an email verification).

- The request is made using Firebase Authentication with a custom handler (with custom domain : https://example.com/auth)
- The `ActionCodeSettings` looks like :

```
final ActionCodeSettings codeSettings = ActionCodeSettings(
      url: 'https://links.example.com/auth?email=$email',
      iOSBundleId: Constants.iosBundleID,
      androidPackageName: Constants.androidBundleID,
      androidInstallApp: true,
      dynamicLinkDomain: "links.example.com",
    );
```

- The user clicks on the link he received by email and gets redirected to the website (hosted by Firebase Hosting under : example.com)
- When the user has finished resetting his password, i would expect to redirect him by "launching" the `continueUrl` that should take him back to the mobile app. `continueUrl` : 'https://links.example.com/auth?email=$email'

However this doesn't work so i am guessing that i am doing something wrong somewhere.

1. In my iOS config, i have added the `Associated Domains` as : `applinks:links.example.com`.
   In the `Info.plist` file i have added :

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://links.example.com/auth</string>
    </array>
```

(and have also tried with : `<string>https://links.example.com</string>`)

2. In my Android config I have added this to my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
               <data android:host="links.example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
           </intent-filter>
```

Fun fact, on Android after the above steps are completed (on website from the smartphone), if i launch the `continueUrl` it prompts the user whether to redirect back to the app or stay on the browser to open the URL.

I have of course created a sub-domain : `links.example.com` in the Firebase Dynamic links console as an URL prefix.

Here are my questions :

- Is the `continueUrl` supposed to redirect back to the app ?
- In the `ActionCodeSettings` `continueUrl` described above is correct? I see in the documentation always using `example.com` as the `continueUrl`, but it would be in conflict with the custom domain used for hosting right ? So i have put `links.example.com` as the `continueUrl` and the custom Firebase auth handler is `example.com/auth` to indeed redirect to the correct web page in my website.
- What is the Hosting `firebase.json` configuration for such case ?
- The final link looks like this :

```
https://example.com/auth?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=T0qn8aj_p7TJBWyE5eUh7_7ZwIqwtJ7Q-i8LDf4QrIsAAAF_u6Bi6Q&apiKey=AIzaSyAzPqhZFKAyfQDeN4DGGjI9VCTEBe_mLc4&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flinks.example.com%3Flink%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Flinks.example.com%2Fauth%3Femail%253Dtestmail12%40gmail.com%26apn%3Dcom.example.android%26amv%26ibi%3Dcom.example.ios%26ifl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Flinks.example.com%2Fauth%3Femail%253Dtestmail12%40gmail.com&lang=fr
```

- Do you see anything wrong or missing ? Something that would prevent the mobile app redirection after the operation completes ?
- What should I do with the `continueUrl` param to gets redirected to the app ? Is it automatically done after some event or should the developer writes code to "push" a new web page containing this link and it will see automatically that's not a link to handle in a web page, thus redirect to the mobile app ?

Thanks a lot in advance for any explanations on how this works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally understood how this works :

The `continueUrl` must be the one used to handle back in the mobile app so if you use :

```
url: 'https://links.example.com/auth?email=$email',
```

This means you have to create a `dynamic link` prefix URL : `https://links.example.com/auth` in the firebase console.

You must also add it to your iOS `Info.plist` file as stated in the question.

Also, when you use a custom domain you need to make sure as stated in the documentation that the URL prefix and the domain are different such as :

```
https://link.example.com/?link=https://example.com/my-resource
```

And not :

```
https://example.com/?link=https://example.com/my-resource
```

This means that by using `https://links.example.com/auth` as URL prefix, you need to use another domain to deal with the link.

In my case, i have built the url this way :

```
https://links.example.com/?link=https://redirect.example.com/auth
```

And added `https://redirect.example.com/auth` as URL prefix.
This prevent both conflicts between `example.com` at the hosting level and `links.example.com` from having both link domain name AND Url prefix identical.

Also, don't forget to add new dynamic links domain as `whitelisted` domains in the Firebase Authentication Sign-In methods in Firebase console or you will get a `domain-denied` error.

Hope this will help others to understand better how this works.